# How to extract information out of a csv file to build a network with nodes and eges?

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with various colums (col1, col2, col3, etc.). The lines are information about events. One of the colums contains the location of the event.
I would like to represent that data as a network with nodes and edges. There would be two kinds of nodes :

- the events : a csv line minus the content of the location column
- the locations : all the locations mentioned in the location column of the csv file

The edges would represent the relationships between the nodes.

Ultimately I would loke to obtain a csv file with the nodes and a csv file with all the relationships between the nodes.

I think a langage like Python would likely be helpful here and I am trying to teach it myself but I would really apreciate some help.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html. Also please show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure on your data, but assuming events can have multiple locations, locations can have multiple events, and there are no edges between two events or two locations, here is a possible solution.

It ignores other event information but you can easily modify it as needed for adding meta data, and it also stores each node with a list of edges, best for sparse data representation.

Here is the mock data in the csv file (format: loc_x loc_y, event name)

```
1x 2y, mission_go
3x 4y, hvi_hiding
5x 6y, maxim11_flying
5x 6y, maxim12_flying
3x 5y, taskforce_observing
3x 5y, king_arthur_call
5x 6y, cleared_hot
3x 4y, target_strike
1x 2y, chow_food
1x 2y, drink_illegal_alchohol
3x 3y, chow_food
3x 3y, drink_illegal_alchohol
```

Here's the code to import the data

```
import csv
import pprint
import collections

# Store the nodes in a dict with edges in a list, assuming sparse data
location_nodes = collections.defaultdict(list)
event_nodes = collections.defaultdict(list)

# Open the csv file and read
with open('/path/to/your_csv_file.csv') as csv_file:
    for event in csv.reader(csv_file):

        # Use each location as a key (node) and list of events (edges)
        location_nodes[event[0]].append(event[1])
        # Same for events
        event_nodes[event[1]].append(event[0])

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
pp.pprint(dict(location_nodes))
print ""
pp.pprint(dict(event_nodes))
```

Here is the printed output

```
{   '1x 2y': [' mission_go', ' chow_food', ' drink_illegal_alchohol'],
    '3x 3y': [' chow_food', ' drink_illegal_alchohol'],
    '3x 4y': [' hvi_hiding', ' target_strike'],
    '3x 5y': [' taskforce_observing', ' king_arthur_call'],
    '5x 6y': [' maxim11_flying', ' maxim12_flying', ' cleared_hot']}

{   ' chow_food': ['1x 2y', '3x 3y'],
    ' cleared_hot': ['5x 6y'],
    ' drink_illegal_alchohol': ['1x 2y', '3x 3y'],
    ' hvi_hiding': ['3x 4y'],
    ' king_arthur_call': ['3x 5y'],
    ' maxim11_flying': ['5x 6y'],
    ' maxim12_flying': ['5x 6y'],
    ' mission_go': ['1x 2y'],
    ' target_strike': ['3x 4y'],
    ' taskforce_observing': ['3x 5y']}
```

The code to save the info back into csv files

```
with open('/path/to/location_node.csv', 'w') as loc_file:
    writer = csv.writer(loc_file)  
    for location in location_nodes:
        location_list = [location]
        location_list.extend(location_nodes[location])
        writer.writerow(location_list)

with open('/path/to/event_node.csv', 'w') as event_file:
    writer = csv.writer(event_file)  
    for event in event_nodes:
        event_list = [event]
        event_list.extend(event_nodes[event])
        writer.writerow(event_list)
```

And what the files look like

location_node.csv

```
3x 5y, taskforce_observing, king_arthur_call
5x 6y, maxim11_flying, maxim12_flying, cleared_hot
3x 4y, hvi_hiding, target_strike
3x 3y, chow_food, drink_illegal_alchohol
1x 2y, mission_go, chow_food, drink_illegal_alchohol
```

event_node.csv

```
 cleared_hot,5x 6y
 drink_illegal_alchohol,1x 2y,3x 3y
 maxim11_flying,5x 6y
 mission_go,1x 2y
 chow_food,1x 2y,3x 3y
 maxim12_flying,5x 6y
 taskforce_observing,3x 5y
 target_strike,3x 4y
 hvi_hiding,3x 4y
 king_arthur_call,3x 5y
```

Would need to see the data to get more specific on munging.